Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException JDBC exception executing SQL Invalid column name 'd'
I am building Spring boot rest application, I am using SQL server 2022, my application get data from DB which created desktop application which is using SQL Server, and I can not change any column name, if I do it, desktop application won't working. This DB is has unstandrd column name for example deptid, deptname, because I can not use JPQL or method param.
8:05:35 AM: Executing ':TheBestReportingApplication.main()'...

> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes

> Task :TheBestReportingApplication.main()

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.2)
```
2024-07-30T08:05:39.948+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] c.r.t.TheBestReportingApplication        : Starting TheBestReportingApplication using Java 17.0.10 with PID 12252 (C:\Users\Shirbidov\Documents\git_projects\the_best_reporting\build\classes\java\main started by Shirbidov in C:\Users\Shirbidov\Documents\git_projects\the_best_reporting)
2024-07-30T08:05:39.955+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] c.r.t.TheBestReportingApplication        : The following 1 profile is active: "db"
2024-07-30T08:05:41.867+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-07-30T08:05:41.991+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 105 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.
2024-07-30T08:05:43.174+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-07-30T08:05:43.196+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-07-30T08:05:43.197+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.26]
2024-07-30T08:05:43.344+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-07-30T08:05:43.347+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3271 ms
2024-07-30T08:05:43.831+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-07-30T08:05:43.977+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.2.Final
2024-07-30T08:05:44.052+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-07-30T08:05:44.755+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-07-30T08:05:44.813+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-07-30T08:05:45.463+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 601bf3f5-a3b6-43f8-b7af-9eca7cf0777a
2024-07-30T08:05:45.467+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-07-30T08:05:45.533+04:00  WARN 12252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: SQLServerDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-07-30T08:05:47.440+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-07-30T08:05:47.444+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-07-30T08:05:47.967+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.r.query.QueryEnhancerFactory     : Hibernate is in classpath; If applicable, HQL parser will be used.
2024-07-30T08:05:48.081+04:00  WARN 12252 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-07-30T08:05:48.975+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-07-30T08:05:48.998+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [           main] c.r.t.TheBestReportingApplication        : Started TheBestReportingApplication in 9.972 seconds (process running for 10.727)
2024-07-30T08:05:53.986+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-07-30T08:05:53.987+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-07-30T08:05:53.990+04:00  INFO 12252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 3 ms
Hibernate: SELECT d FROM Dept d WHERE d.deptid =? 
2024-07-30T08:05:54.382+04:00  WARN 12252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 207, SQLState: S0001
2024-07-30T08:05:54.383+04:00 ERROR 12252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid column name 'd'.
2024-07-30T08:05:54.408+04:00 ERROR 12252 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [SELECT d FROM Dept d WHERE d.deptid =? ] [Invalid column name 'd'.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'd'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:261) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1752) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:686) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:605) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7748) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:4410) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:293) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:263) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:520) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractResultSetAccess.getMetaData(AbstractResultSetAccess.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractResultSetAccess.getColumnCount(AbstractResultSetAccess.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.results.ResultSetMappingImpl.resolve(ResultSetMappingImpl.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.resolveJdbcValuesSource(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:327) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeSelectQueryPlanImpl.performList(NativeSelectQueryPlanImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:628) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:423) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:555) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:223) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:152) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:140) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:379) ~[spring-tx-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-tx-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy114.findByDeptID(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.reporting.the_best_reporting.service.DeptServiceImpl.findByDeptID(DeptServiceImpl.java:21) ~[main/:na]
    at com.reporting.the_best_reporting.rest.DeptController.getById(DeptController.java:21) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar:10.1.26]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) ~[na:na]
```

git : https://gitlab.com/Shirbidov/the_best_reporting.git
@Query(value = "SELECT d FROM Dept d WHERE d.deptid =:id ")


Ditch your findByDeptId method and use findById, you don't need a custom query for this. Don't use @Data on entities (See my own blog on this https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/) as that will lead to issues.

Looking at your code comments in com.reporting.the_best_reporting.domain.Dept, it looks like you have two columns DeptId and DeptName.
If you're trying to get DeptName, change your Query annotation value to:
 SELECT deptname FROM Dept d WHERE d.deptid =:id 

If you're wanting to get all the columns, use the following:
SELECT * FROM Dept d WHERE d.deptid =:id


Hibernate: SELECT * FROM Dept d WHERE d.deptid =? Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.reporting.the_best_reporting.dto.DeptResponseDto]] with root cause

org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.reporting.the_best_reporting.dto.DeptResponseDto]

You need to setup a converter, either via a constructor or interface.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-converter-exception has some examples.

I think that the problem is on the DB column name: "deptName" and now I write on repository :   @Query(value = "select d.deptName from Dept d where d.deptid =:id")
Dept findByIDBySQL(@Param("id") Long id); and it give query on the console : executing SQL [select d1_0.dept_name from dept d1_0 where d1_0.deptid=?] [Invalid column name 'dept_name'.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause
Invalid column name 'dept_name'. column name is : "deptname" but spring write it as "dept_name" but if I do not use deptName on the entity my project is run wirhout problem
